# How to use DynamicResource from the codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I often write the following code in the XAML:

```
(...)
xmlns:vs="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0"
(...)

<Path Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static vs:VsBrushes.GrayText}}">
```

How can I create such `Path` from the codebehind? (precisely: how to attach the DynamicResource to the dependency property?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps: [FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:** in your case it should look like this:

```
pathObject.SetResourceReference(Path.FillProperty, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsBrushes.GrayText);
```

I don't know why the documentation says that the second parameter should be Object name, it actually accepts the resource `Key`.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer half of your question with the [`FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference.aspx):

```
PathName.SetResourceReference(Path.FillProperty, "NameOfBrush");
```

However, I'm not quite sure how you'd use your `vs:VsBrushes.GrayText Brush` with it.

Comment: That's very simple :) `PathName.SetResourceReference(Path.FillProperty, VsBrushes.GrayText)` (after `#using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell`)